# How to show my post type TEAM in dynamic way?

Tags: custom-post-types

**Hi everyone,**

I am starting now to develoo my first wordpress Theme and please, I need your help with code.

With this code I created my post type Team, the problem is to show them, I do not know how to do it.
If it's possible, I wish to create some easy option for users in Bakery page builder  to add it in a row with the option for slider. How can I do it ?

**Thanks for any information**

```
function create_post_type() {

    register_post_type( 'Team',
        array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => __( 'Team' ),
            'singular_name' => __( 'Team' ),
            'add_new' => __( 'Add Member' ),
            'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Member' ),
            'featured_image' => __( 'Add Photo' ),
            'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Member' )
        ),
        'public' => true,
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-universal-access',
        'has_archive' => true,
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'Team'),
        'supports' => array('title', 'editor','custom-fields', 'thumbnail'),
        )
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );
```

Comment: Where you want to display this post_type entries?

Comment: In the home page for example, but with option for user put it anywhere.

Comment: You can create a shortcode for it. And can call anywhere on the website, you just need to call it. I'll share more detail in comment section.

Comment: Check Answer section.

Answer (score 1):

As you said in a comment that you want to make it dynamic and wants to call anywhere of the website. Then in WP the best option is to use the shortcode. You can create a short code and call it where ever you want. One thing you can update it's design as per your need, I am sharing a way to create a short code for the CPT.

```
/**
 * Register all shortcodes
 *
 * @return null
 */
function register_shortcodes() {
    add_shortcode( 'produtos', 'shortcode_mostra_produtos' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_shortcodes' );
/**
 * Produtos Shortcode Callback
 * 
 * @param Array $atts
 *
 * @return string
 */
function shortcode_mostra_produtos( $atts ) {
    global $wp_query,$post;
    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'line' => ''
    ), $atts );

    $loop = new WP_Query( array(
        'posts_per_page'    => 200,
        'post_type'         => 'produtos',
        'orderby'           => 'menu_order title',
        'order'             => 'ASC',
        'tax_query'         => array( array(
            'taxonomy'  => 'linhas',
            'field'     => 'slug',
            'terms'     => array( sanitize_title( $atts['line'] ) )
        ) )
    ) );

    if( ! $loop->have_posts() ) {
        return false;
    }

    while( $loop->have_posts() ) {
        $loop->the_post();
        echo the_title();
    }

    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

I have created a shortcode for the products to display the product list.

Now you can add [produtos] on the wp backend page/post and after saving this will display the produts title (as i only echo the title) on the front end.

For more reference about the shortcode API you can follow this article [SHORTCODE API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API)

Try this. I think this will help you. Let me know if you will face any issue here.

Enjoy!!:)

Comment: Thank you so much Arpita. I am going to do it !

Comment: Let me know Alander, If you face any issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `WP_Query` or `get_posts` to achieve the result. Here I'm providing you an example using `WP_Query` of how you can achieve what you need.

```
$args = array(  
    'post_type' => 'Team',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1, // -1 will return all entry
    'orderby' => 'title', 
    'order' => 'ASC',
);

$loop = new WP_Query( $args ); 

while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 
    $featured_img = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $post->ID );
    echo the_title(); // Print the title
    if ( $feature_img ) {
       //Print image if available
       echo '<img src="'.$featured_img['url'].'" width="'.$featured_img['width'].'" height="'.$featured_img['height'].'" />';
    }
    the_excerpt(); 
endwhile;

wp_reset_postdata();
```

You can study more about **WP_Query** [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/). Also read about **get_posts()** [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_posts/). Have fun!

Comment: Thank you Sabbir. I will study what you said. Regards